# How to get bit from bytearray in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get the particular bit value from bytearray. I tried and its working fine, but let me know is there any optimize way to do this.

```py
in_bytes = bytearray()
in_bytes .extend([5,10,15]) # output : bytearray(b'\x05\n\x0f')
tk = in_bytes [0]
bk = in_bytes [1]
sk = in_bytes [2]
print(tk, bk, sk) # 5 10 15
bk = 10 << 8
sk = 15 << 16
res = sk | bk | tk
print(res) # 985605

def get_bit_value(number, bit_position):
    return (number >> bit_position) & 1
bit_value = get_bit_value(985605, 2)
print(bit_value) #
```

From this bytearray b'\x05\n\x0f', how can i get particular bit value?

Comment: What do you mean by optimized? This code is doing several things, which of them do you mean?

Comment: I think this would be better suited to [codereview.se]. It's too broad for SO.

Comment: @mkrieger1 From this bytearray b'\x05\n\x0f', how can i get particular bit value?